# Remove unwanted characters after using file.readlines()

Tags: python

I've tried using `lines.split()` and `lines.strip()` but could not manage to remove the following: `' ', \n or #`.

```py
>>> f = open('example.txt')
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> lines
['#\n', '2.1,-3.1\n', '-0.7,4.1\n', '#\n', '3.8,1.5\n', '-1.2,1.1']

Needing this output
[2.1, -3.1, -0.7, 4.1, 3.8, 1.5, -1.2, 1.1]
```

Comment: Use str.replace and replace the unwanted characters with `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first remove the newlines. Then strip, clean based on the `#` character. The code is as follows:

```
a = [i.strip() for i in lines]
b = [float(j) for i in a for j in i.split(",") if "#" not in j]
```

The output is as follows:

```
>>> a
['#', '2.1,-3.1', '-0.7,4.1', '#', '3.8,1.5', '-1.2,1.1']
>>> b
[2.1, -3.1, -0.7, 4.1, 3.8, 1.5, -1.2, 1.1]
```